# Counting Characters in C++

Tags: c++

Not sure why my loop isn't working, it keeps sticking every time I try an input :/
Am hoping for an onput that just shows the count of the diffent types which I've listed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
int main() {
char ch;
int puncCount = 0;
int letterCount = 0;
int digitCount = 0;
int spaceCount = 0;

cout << "The characters which you'd like!" << endl;
cout << "Type a line with a single 'Q' to stop \n" << endl;
cin.get(ch);

while (ch != 'q')
{

    letterCount += isalpha(ch);
    puncCount += ispunct(ch);
    digitCount += isalnum(ch);
    spaceCount += isspace(ch);

}

cout << "Letter count is"  << letterCount << endl;
cout << "Puncuation count is" << puncCount << endl;
cout << "Digit count is" << digitCount << endl;
cout << "Space count is" << spaceCount << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to put another call to get input within the loop:

```
while (ch != 'q')
{
    // ...
    cin.get(ch);
}
```

Comment: @XTyke No problem. Don't forget to check for 'Q' as well.

Comment: If this answer was sufficient to solve your problem @XTyke, then you should mark it as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not repeating the call to get the characters in the loop.  Also, check for 'q' and'Q' if that is your aim.